# How can I resolve a this failed deployment on a Windows phone Azure Application?

Tags: azure, windows-phone

I have a problem in my windows phone azure application.

I have done all the steps completely but I'm getting a **Deployment Failed** error in the publishing step.

The Error detail is:

> 7:49:13 AM - Verifying storage account 'volstorage'...
>   7:49:15 AM - Uploading Package...
>   7:49:17 AM - Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of   Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
>   7:49:18 AM - Deployment failed

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

A common reason is because the time on your machine isn't configured correctly. Could you monitor the traffic (incl. HTTPS) using Fiddler?

The detail of the error should say something like this: **Request date header too old**. This can be solved by setting your time correctly.

If this isn't the issue, please use Fiddler to find the detail and update your question.

Comment: I installed this programm and it affected many of my application in my PC,however i went to the CMOS in the windows and fixed the time is that enough?????

Comment: I doubt it. Could you start Fiddler, then start Visual Studio and deploy the application. You should see a red line in Fiddler (the error when you deploy to Windows Azure). Could you post the detail of that red line?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is unable to deploy to Windows Azure. Could you please make sure you’ve uploaded the management certificate to the portal, and choose the same certificate in Visual Studio when you are publishing the application? I would like to suggest you to check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg981929.aspx for more information.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Comment: There're two kinds of certificates in Windows Azure. Please make sure you've uploaded the certificate to "Management Certificates". Please also check if you've selected the same certificate in Visual Studio. If it still doesn't work, you can also use the portal to deploy the application to see whether it works fine.

Comment: hi Minh, any advise to fix the issue with the Visual Studio while deploying the application by using portal works?